# Массив и localStorage

Tags: jquery, localstorage

Как сохранять и извлекать массив из localStorage?
Пробовал пару вариантов - и ничего..
То в нём храниться `object`, то тупо текстом, то ещё что-нибудь.

Код:

```
var $arrNightMode = ["false","false","23","07"];

$('#activeNM, #activeNMtimer').on('click',function(){
    if($('#activeNM').prop('checked')) $arrNightMode[0] = "true"; else $arrNightMode[0] = "false";
    if($('#activeNMtimer').prop('checked')) $arrNightMode[1] = "true"; else $arrNightMode[1] = "false";

    localStorage.setItem('NightMode',JSON.stringify($arrNightMode));
});

$('#timeON, #timeOFF').bind('change',function(){
    var NumberVal = $(this).val(); 
    if(NumberVal<10) $(this).val('0'+NumberVal);

    $arrNightMode[2] = $('#timeON').val();
    $arrNightMode[3] = $('#timeOFF').val();

    localStorage.setItem('NightMode',JSON.stringify($arrNightMode));
});

if(!localStorage.getItem('NightMode')){
    localStorage.setItem('NightMode', $arrNightMode);
} else {
    var $arrNightMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('NightMode'));
    var isActiveNM = arrNightMode[0];
    var isActiveNMtimer = arrNightMode[1];
    var isTimeON = arrNightMode[2];
    var isTimeOFF = arrNightMode[3];
    if(isActiveNM=='false') $('#activeNM').prop('checked',true);
}
```

Comment: С виду код рабочий (хоть и костыльный), за исключением, что вы используете `$arrNightMode`, а допустим в `isActiveNM ` пишете `arrNightMode[0]` без `$`, а так вроде должно все работать - вообще ошибка которую вы привели в комменте, говорит о том, что `JSON.parse` - пытается разобрать то, что не является строкой. А значит вы, что-то упускаете из виду, чего собственно не видно по этому коду. Как вариант - смотреть, что происходит после `JSON.stringify` и вывести результат ее работы. [bad parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хранить можно всё то, что сможет уложиться в строку, так как единственным разрешенным типом данных для хранения является текстовый тип — строка.

```
var array = [4, 5, 6];
localStorage.setItem('array',JSON.stringify(array));
array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('array'));
console.log(array[2]); //6
```

Comment: Консоль выдаёт ошибку `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 6 of the JSON data`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, А вы, после `JSON.stringify`, покажите какие данные? И вообще, покажите, что вы пытаетесь за массив передавать, явно с ним, что-то не так. Обновите свой вопрос, желательно полными данными, ничего не обрезайте, а то лишнего обрежете и ошибку не будет видно.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос